# comparing dates in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, date, datetime, meteor

A Meteor server code updates a Mongodb collection, `dateField` has value looking like this
 `ISODate("2016-11-19T00:00:00Z")`

The client selects a `dateStart` and `dateFinish`, look like this
     $('input[name="startDateStr"]').val() // => "2016-11-19"

So I convert the user entry so that I can use it to get the documents with the `dateField` matching the below mongodb query;

```
dateToISO: (date) => { // date format in YYYY-MM-DD
  const dArr = date.split('-');
  return new Date(parseInt(dArr[0]), parseInt(dArr[1]) - 1, parseInt(dArr[2]));
}
```

And then present the results to the user with the date in the formate DD/MM/YYYY

```js
      let start = utility.dateToISO(dict.get('inquiryStartDate'));
      let end = utility.dateToISO(dict.get('inquiryEndDate'));

////Both of the above prints: Sat Nov 19 2016 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (AEDT)

     return myCol.find({
        date: {
          $gte: start,
          $lte: end
        }
      }, {
        transform: function(doc) {
          doc.date = moment(doc.date).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
          return doc;
        }
      });
```

The code fails to return any documents event though some exist. Any idea why and how to fix it?

Comment: You comment in your code that `Both of the above prints: Sat Nov 19 2016 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (AEDT)` so that only documents having date field whose value is exact `Sat Nov 19 2016 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (AEDT)` will be return.

Comment: does it work when you remove the $lte:end from query ?

Comment: @Khang What is the best to convert one date to the formate of the other in order for this compression to take place? Now sure if that is the problem since the same code works fine if the date value changes.

Comment: @Veeram Yes it does work. But I don't understand why and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new Date(year, month, date) variant  will have the date in current system time zone.

The reason you comparison doesn't return any results is when you pass the date in your local system zone , the meteor does a conversion from local datetime to UTC datetime as Mongo DB datetimes are in UTC time. So your input date changes from  Sat Nov 19 2016 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (AEDT) to Fri Nov 18, 2016 01:00:00 UTC.

Considering user inputs date as UTC.  You'll just need to parse the date explicitly as UTC.

Try

```
new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 11, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

and pass this to the query.