# Issue creating monthly report using `$gte` and `$lte` operators

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

There's a bug I found when trying to create a sales today. With below query I couldn't find the sales data that was just created today. My date here is 1/12/2016.

My express.js controller as below

```
function firstDayOfMonth(given_month) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setMonth(given_month, 1);
  return d.toISOString();
}

function lastDayOfMonth(given_month) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setMonth(given_month + 1, 0);
  return d.toISOString();
}

Sales.find({
  "subscriber_email": req.body.user_email,
  "createAt": {
    "$gte": firstDayOfMonth(given_month),
    "$lte": lastDayOfMonth(given_month)
  }
}).sort('-createAt').exec(callback);
```

Is the use of $gte is wrong here? given month is dynamic but that doesn't matter, the problem is my newly create sales record on 1/12/2016 appear in November.

Comment: Can you add some sample records where it is not working? Just wanted to see how they look in db

Comment: @Veeram no sample records needed, I think it's the logic problem? else it's timezone problem then. I don't know. Just now there's a sales record created on 1/12/2016 but above code grouped it together with the records of november.

Comment: It is a time zone problem but wanted to confirm before I tell you that. The records in mongodb are in UTC datetime  and new Date creates datetime in local time zone. Use Date.UTC to create datetime before comparing

Comment: so to solve this problem I have to use new Date in UTC?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40692249/2683814 please take a look at this.

Comment: @Veeram I think it's better 'to ask' mongo's date to don't convert to UTC, because by doing that I don't have to convert the new Date at all.

Comment: Mongo by design take dates in UTC. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/ and all drivers are built to support this way.

Comment: @Veeram there's no way to save in datetime of local machine of users?

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid as I don't think that is possible.