# How to compare date without time in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to compare 2 iso dates using only the day without time, in Mongo DB. I want this query just like SQL.

```
select * from data where DATE_FORMAT("data.effectivestartdate", "%Y-%m-%d")
 < DATE_FORMAT("2018-11-13T23:59:59+05:30’", "%Y-%m-%d");
```

How can I write this query in Mongo DB?
Kindly modified this query.

```
db.entityrecord.find({
 "data.effectivestartdate": { "$lte": ISODate("2018-11-13T23:59:59+05:30") })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690827/comparing-dates-in-mongodb ?

Comment: You can refer this link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272471/mongodb-comparing-dates-only-without-times

Comment: Does this answer your question? [comparing dates in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690827/comparing-dates-in-mongodb)